# How to extract data from one database table and insert into another database table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, automation, database-administration

Suppose we have two databases on different servers one database is at server1: 192.168.1.11 and another database at server2: 192.168.1.12 and weekly we need to export data from server1 to server2 manually to do some report.

**We can do it manually. How can I do it using python or any other opensource tools easily in a Linux system?**

Is it possible to get data from one database and import it into another database using python script?

MSSQL has a tool that is called SSIS.

**But what for PostgreSQL, is it possible using python psycopg2 package?** (just get results set from one source and insert into another destination)

**If possible then how can we get data from server1 and insert into server2?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you sure you want python for this? have you tried `pg_dump` to export and `psql` for import? [tutorial](https://www.netguru.com/blog/how-to-dump-and-restore-postgresql-database)

Comment: Use [postgres_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html) and set up a direct connection between the two.

Comment: @Jossef Harush Kadouri
 I am not interested to do it manually using pg_dump